# git update issues using brew

Tags: git

I'm using brew to update git. It says that it has completed the update and I now have 1.8.2 (yay!)

Unfortunately there are still issues

`git --version` still returns `git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)`
`where git` returns `/usr/bin/git`

I went and I made sure my path was correct since that would mess things up if my `/usr/bin/` was in front of my `/usr/local/bin`

`echo $PATH` returned `/usr/local/bin:...:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

I'm obviously missing something any thoughts or comments are apprecitated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean `which git` instead of `where git` ?

Can you check the content of `/usr/local/bin` to check if `git` is there ?

`ls -l /usr/local/bin`

Try to check the content of PATH from a new terminal window, to see if it is properly setup with `/usr/local/bin` before everything else.

Comment: checked the path and it wasn't there. Turns out that brew needed to set up symlinks and there was a failure during that stage of the process

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the PATH variable on my .bash_profile file like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

It works very good.

Hope it helps.